# Return most common occurrence of value in a group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, matching, ranking

I have a query that is doing conditional matching on records for the sake of creating a "golden record" on a people table.  In doing so, another requirement is to rank attributes within the matches by the most common occurrence so that the golden record has the best values.  This is an over simplification of the process I am working on but it does show what I'm trying to do.

I believe what I have is working, but I think there is probably better ways to do it.  I have separated each logic step into a temp table to better demonstrate what I'm doing.

- Step1: Self Join to match on multiple rules. This or that or that...
- Step2: Rank attributes within matching records by Count (occurrence)
- Step3: Create a Golden Record for the matches and choose which
  Attributes win base on previous steps' counts Step4: Assign Golden
  Records to original People records

Here's some example data and my existing queries to show the logical steps:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
FirstName varchar(255),  
LastName varchar(255),    
Address1 varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
State varchar(255),
BDay Varchar(255),
Email Varchar(255)
);


INSERT INTO Persons
SELECT 'RICK', 'ALLEN', '44 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '1/2/1970','help@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNIFER', 'ALLEN', '123 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '4/8/1980','test@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNIFER', 'ALLEN', '123 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '4/8/1981','test@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNIFER', 'ALLEN', '42 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '4/8/1980','test@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNIFER', 'ALLEN', '123 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '4/8/1980','test2@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STEVEN', 'ALLEN', '555 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '2/8/1980','help@test.com'




SELECT * FROM Persons;

SELECT  p1.FirstName
, p1.LastName
, p1.Address1
, p1.BDay
, p1.Email
, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY p2.ID) AS [MatchCount]
, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY p2.ID, p1.FirstName) AS [MatchCount_FirstName]
, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY p2.ID, p1.Address1) AS [MatchCount_Address1]
, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY p2.ID, p1.BDay) AS [MatchCount_BDay]
, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY p2.ID, p1.Email) AS [MatchCount_Email]
, p1.ID as OriginalID
, p2.ID as DupeID
INTO #tmp_dups
FROM Persons p1
INNER JOIN    Persons p2
ON      p1.FirstName = p2.FirstName AND
        p1.LastName = p2.LastName AND
        (
            p1.Address1 = p2.Address1 OR
            p1.BDay = p2.BDay OR
            p1.Email = p2.Email
        )

SELECT  MIN(a.OriginalID) as OriginalID
    , a.DupeID
INTO #tmp_matches
FROM #tmp_dups AS a
GROUP BY a.DupeID

SELECT 
    *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [DupeID] ORDER BY [MatchCount_FirstName] DESC) AS [Match_RankByCount_FirstName]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [DupeID] ORDER BY [MatchCount_Address1] DESC) AS [Match_RankByCount_Address1]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [DupeID] ORDER BY [MatchCount_BDay] DESC) AS [Match_RankByCount_BDay]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [DupeID] ORDER BY [MatchCount_Email] DESC) AS [Match_RankByCount_Email]
INTO #tmp_rankdups
FROM #tmp_dups


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.DupeID) + 100000 AS GoldenRecordID  
    --, MIN(a.OriginalID) as OriginalID
    , a.DupeID        
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [Match_RankByCount_FirstName] = 1 THEN a.[FirstName] END) AS [FirstName]
    , a.LastName
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [Match_RankByCount_Address1] = 1 THEN a.[address1] END) AS [address1]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [Match_RankByCount_BDay] = 1 THEN a.[BDay] END) AS [BDay]
    , MIN(CASE WHEN [Match_RankByCount_Email] = 1 THEN a.[Email] END) AS [Email]
INTO #tmp_goldenrecords
FROM #tmp_rankdups AS a
GROUP BY a.DupeID        
    , a.LastName
HAVING MIN(a.OriginalID) = a.DupeID

SELECT * FROM Persons AS p
INNER JOIN #tmp_matches AS m
    ON p.ID = m.DupeID
INNER JOIN #tmp_goldenrecords AS g
    ON g.DupeID = m.OriginalID
```

Comment: Looks good. I would only suggest replacing the #tmp_tables with CTEs so you don't have to write logic to drop if exists on your temp tables between runs...unless you are that good :)

Comment: Sheldon joke: in answer to a guess who? he answers Mohammed Lee since Mohammed is the most common first name and Lee is the most common surname. This approach to finding a golden record seems to fall into the same trap.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com since it is working code seeking improvements / critique

Comment: @scsimon It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Thanks for the post. I always found it odd that stats.stackexchange was a default option, but not codereview, thus I used the custom method. I just didn't want to discourage CodeMonkey, but rather steer them to somewhere that it could garner more attention. My bad